# Next JS _middleware does not allow use of dynamic evaluation 'new Function'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, next.js, middleware

I am creating a [_middleware.ts](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware) file for my next js app in order to provide dynamic redirects from data stored on Nacelle. I was successful on localhost, but when deploying to vercel, the build crashed due to "Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function') not allowed in Middleware pages/_middleware".

The reason being, inside _middleware I am including a file which creates an api client as so, but this is not allowed as stated in the next js docs.

```
    export default new NacelleClient({
        id: ex,
        token: ex,
        endpoint: ex,
    })
```

I am fairly new to next js and react so I am not very familiar with getServerSideProps or getStaticPaths. Can anyone inform me how I can successfully do this? If I need to use serverSideProps or getStaticPaths, how can I make the request, obtain the data, and pass it to _middleware? Thank you for any input and time, it is much appreciated.

Comment: Any news? Same error when trying to use Web3Token.verify inside _middleware.ts